# How can I add a breakpoint to build-in nodejs function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

This must be quite a naive question.

I would like to understand node better. And I am trying to see how a buildin function gets called. I may also want to do some minor modification to the buildin function (probably just add a `console.log` statement)

Assume I just have following line code, I would like to see how the constructor function of Promise gets called. How can I setup breakpoint in which source file? (I have put many breakpoints in the `node_modules/core-js/es6/promise.js`, but it seems no line is hit.). I am using vscode as the IDE.

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(1)});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can add breakpoints to builtin functions. But if there is a `node_modules/…` file that defines your promises, it doesn't seem to be native but rather a polyfill?

Comment: @Bergi I don't know about polyfill, but what I do now is that even if I deleted `node_modules/core-js/` folder, the program is still runnable. So where is library that includes `Promise` that gets called? I'm really curious about this.

Comment: `Promise` is not a *library*, that's the whole point. It's a native object instantiated by the vm.